# SQL Query challenge

Tags: mysql

I have what seemed like an easy query to write, that really has me stumped - can anyone help me please?

So this is really easy on paper, but I can't translate it into SQL.
Lets say you have some graph data:

> x |  y
>
> 1 |  5.5
>
> 2 |  8
>
> 3 |  2
>
> 4 |  3
>
> 5 |  1

And you essentially want to draw a line sloping down on *top* of the data, touching at least 2 of the top-most points, like this...
[image: graph]

To find when new data steps above this line-- So I am thinking this comes down to the basic formula for a graph y=A + Bx
So, if we know A and B, for a given value of x, we can predict y (and more importantly whether new values of y are above or below the value we predict for y based on this line).

Can anyone help please?

If it helps anyone, very quick create & data statement...

> create table graph1 (x int, y decimal(4,2));
>
> insert into graph1 values (1,5.5),(2,8),(3,2),(4,3),(5,1);

I can do a least squares regression to generate an equation for the linear regression (a line through the middle of the data) - but how would I generate one for the top of the channel the data sits in??

Comment: Verify the accuracy of your illustration... it seems like if (2,8) and (4,3) are true then you have a rise/run of -2.5/1 so the line would intersect (5,0.5) so (5,1) is actually above the line, not below. Right?

Comment: Clearly its not meant to be to scale - it was for illistrative purposes only - what's important is the SQL code that will work with any example.

Comment: Do you know that there could be more than one solutions (lines) to the problem? Do you want the query to find them all?

Comment: Michael -- A more accurate graph has been added! :-)

Comment: ypercube - Hmm, I realise there are an infinite number of possible linear regressions for the best fit of the middle of the data, I wasn't aware there would be more than one possible fit for the top of the data -- but at this point   I would be more than happy with just a best effort for the top please! (I think whats lacking my side is the maths)

Comment: Notice now that one of the top two points is different, (5,1) replaces (4,3). :)  Now, it appears you've actually asked for two different things... find the top line... and identify "whether new data steps above this line".  Which of these two is the one you are looking to solve?  Find the line for a set of data? Or given the two points on the already-known line, identify whether the data points in the table are above, below, or on it?

Comment: Sorry I don't see what you mean about (5,1) and (4,3)...? They are just example data I chose at random.  There is only one thing I want to be able to do -- to calculate a formula which describes a line which fits across the top of this data, touching the 2 "top most" points --which in this data **if drawn accurately**  it would be the points at (2,8) and (5,1) -- however the tricky part is to identify those 2 points out of a table of data

Comment: I don't want to be too specific in case I lead peope off in the wrong direction (as the directions I've tried are wrong!)

Comment: You problem is called [Pareto (efficient) front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier) or [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). I had answered a similar question in SO, some years ago: [How to write a query selecting reasonable trade-offs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682552/how-to-write-a-query-selecting-reasonable-trade-offs) (but that answer is without the "efficient", just the Pareto front.)

Comment: The query (and especially with your extra requirement) would be so much easier to write if only MySQL had recursive CTEs.

Comment: Looks good -- lots of reading for me to do! Thanks ypercube

Comment: Not a direct answer, but maybe a solution to your problem: If you calculate the trend line (regression) for your data, and then calculate the MAX distance of points above this line, you can check for each new point if its distance from the trend-line is bigger than the MAX-Distance - so you could find any points which are a bigger deviation than any current...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole set of lines that satisfy the problem are known as a **[Pareto efficient front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier)** (or frontier or set) or the **[convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)** problem.
<sub>*(See also my answer in the similar question at StackOverflow: **[How to write a query selecting reasonable trade-offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682552/how-to-write-a-query-selecting-reasonable-trade-offs)**).*</sub>

So, one way to solve would be to identify first the points of the front, with a query like below. I assume there is a unique constraint on `(x)`:

```
CREATE TABLE pareto AS
SELECT a.x
     , a.y
FROM graph1 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM graph1 AS b
    WHERE b.x > a.x
      AND b.y >= a.y
  ) ;

SELECT *
FROM pareto ;
```

This would result in:

```
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
| 2.00 | 8.00 |
| 4.00 | 3.00 |
| 5.00 | 1.00 |
+------+------+
```

The lines that pass through these points are our candidates. We have to eliminate however the points (like (4,3)) where another line passes above it. This would be much easier with a recursive CTE but MySQL has not implemented CTEs at all.

The query would not be hard to write - but you do need to experiment with adding some indexes on the temp table (you might even make it a normal InnoDB table), especially if the number of points is high:

```
SELECT p.x
     , p.y
FROM pareto AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS   
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM pareto AS st 
          CROSS JOIN pareto AS en
        WHERE st.x < p.x 
          AND p.x < en.x 
          AND (p.x * (en.y-st.y) + p.y * (en.x-st.x) < 0)
      ) ;
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
| 2.00 | 8.00 |
| 5.00 | 1.00 |
+------+------+
```

If the number of points expected at this point is high (like 1000+) a SQL query for MySQL would probably be inefficient as it would require a 3-way cross join (of the temp table). Another option would be to have a query that uses mysql variables and runs through the (temp) table in order of the `x` coordinate, eliminating the covered points - either in one or multiple batches.

---

Another option would be to write the whole query in one go. Good for testing with small data - but I wouldn't even try it if there were millions of rows:

```
SELECT a.x
     , a.y
FROM graph1 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM graph1 AS b
        WHERE b.x > a.x
          AND b.y >= a.y
      ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS   
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM graph1 AS st 
          CROSS JOIN graph1 AS en
        WHERE st.x < a.x 
          AND a.x < en.x 
          AND (a.x * (en.y-st.y) + a.y * (en.x-st.x) < 0)
      ) ;
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
| 2.00 | 8.00 |
| 5.00 | 1.00 |
+------+------+
```

---

Note for all the queries. I would prefer if both `x` and `y` where the same type (so make x `decimal(4,2)` as y).

An index on `(x,y)` would be used by both queries.

Comment: Amazing!!  I was also looking at using the least squares regression (as quick to execute) -- and this could be used to cut down the amount of data feeding into your query. Thank you so much! (I would vote up but I only a noobie here so not allowed yet)

Comment: (I realise this wasn't part of my original  question) I'm now looking at getting the lower most co-ordinates. I tried reversing the query, but its the last line thats foxing me, I've got...

Comment: SELECT a.x, a.y  FROM graph1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM graph1 b
        WHERE b.x < a.x
          AND b.y <= a.y
      ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS   
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM graph1 st 
          CROSS JOIN graph1 en
        WHERE st.x > a.x 
          AND a.x > en.x 
          AND (a.x * (st.y-en.y) + a.y * (st.x-en.x) > 0)
      ) ;

Comment: Your query seems right. it return 3 points (1, 5.5) (3,2) and (5,1). I would have written it as `SELECT a.x, a.y FROM graph1 a WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM graph1 b WHERE b.x < a.x AND b.y <= a.y ) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM graph1 st CROSS JOIN graph1 en WHERE st.x < a.x AND a.x < en.x AND (a.x * (en.y-st.y) + a.y * (en.x-st.x) > 0) ) ;` but the result is the same

Comment: I was trying to get rid of that (5,1) -- but if I'm understanding Pareto correctly thats also a valid candidate - thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the 2 lines from below (one from (1, 5.5) to ((3,2) and the next from (3,2) to (5,1)) have all the other points above it.